# How do I extract the contents of a string within a ReSharper Pattern?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, resharper-5.x

I've got the following problem:

I want to replace a hardcoded string which contains a property name with a LINQ member expression

```
// like this:
NotifyOfPropertyChange("MyProperty");
// becomes
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyProperty);
```

with a ReSharper pattern.

The following attempts didn't work:

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange("$prop$"); // ($prop$ is of type Identifier, results in parse error)
NotifyOfPropertyChange($prop$); // ($prop$ is of type Expression [System.String],  
                                // almost works, but without removing the quotes
```

The replace pattern was always the same:

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => $prop$);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need R#'s Structural Search and Replace here (which is fortunate, because I don't think in the present version it can do this). Visual Studio's Find and Replace regexes should be good enough:

```
Find What: 
NotifyPropertyChange\("{.*}"\)
```

The `( )` are escaped so that they dontg become a grouping construct; the `{ }` tag whatever matches the pattern within to make them available to the replace expression

```
Replace with:
NotifyPropertyChange(() => \1)
```

Everything here is literal except `\1`, which means 'the first tagged expression'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention correctly then this maybe will help.
Some time ago I found this piece of code ( can't remember who posted it originally)

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    }
```

So the following:

```
NotifyPropertyChange( () => MyProperty)
```

should give a result:

```
NotifyPropertyChange("MyProperty")
```

Comment: I believe he's asking about using R#s Structural Search and Replace, rather than doing anything at execution time